# Can the NE555 reset pin remain floating?

Tags: 555

It seems the reset pin on the NE555 is connected to a PNP which could be left open instead of to upper rail.

What are the drawbacks of leaving the reset pin floating?

Comment: Do you have a definitive schematic of the internals of the device? Have you checked with the data sheet to establish that your assertion is viable?

Comment: The ST datasheet contains an schematic. But only contains information for "lowering" the RESET. https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/ne555.pdf

Comment: And, i never connected the Reset pin. So it works for hobbyist purposes. But I was wondering what could go wrong.

Comment: Read the bottom of page 8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Can the NE555 reset pin remain floating?*

From the data sheet you linked (at the bottom of page 8): -

[image]

From the Diodes Inc [data sheet](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/NE555_SA555_NA555.pdf) (page 7): -

[image]

And, just in case the recommendations for connecting the reset pin to Vcc are a recent thing, here is a picture of the 1973 [Signetics data sheet](https://components101.com/sites/default/files/2021-08/NE555-Datasheet.pdf) (page 9): -

[image]

Maybe there is a 1972 version when the device first came out that someone can find?

Comment: Now I am wondering *why* it might trigger a reset, but that is another question. As I kindof agree, the answer to this one is obvious in retrospect

Comment: It's never a good idea to leave input pins floating @SteveSchnepp

Comment: I knew about it on CMOS, but didn't for TTL tech.

Comment: At least one of the [example circuits](https://i.imgur.com/4mE7waZ.png) in your link has the /RESET pin left open during operation.

Comment: They clearly haven't taken their own advice.

Answer (score 4):

Drawback is it might not work at all, or it might work intermittently or unreliably.

Direct quote from TI NE555 data sheet:

> To prevent false triggering, when RESET is not used, it should be connected to VCC.

The above quote is identical with what reads in Diodes Incorporated NE555 data sheet.

Direct quote from ST NE555 data sheet:

> When Reset is not used, it should be tied high to avoid any possibility of unwanted triggering

Even if you have never had a problem leaving it open, it does not mean it is a good idea to leave it open as it might not always work.

Answer (score 2):

1. It costs nothing to have RESET connected.
2. If someone were to ever get your circuit and replaced the bipolar 555 with a CMOS 555, they’d be in trouble with an open input pin. They could get spurious triggering, excessive current consumption (potentially up to self-destruction at higher supply voltages and temperatures), and generally the circuit wouldn’t act reliably at all.

On the balance, I think there’s no reason *not* to connect it.

Comment: The "no surprise" factor when you replace with a compatible part is indeed a very good reason. Wondering about the inners of a cmos ne555 now

Comment: CMOS inputs generally can't be left floating. This applies to *any* CMOS logic device.